# Foundation 5 positioning issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having an issue positioning an icon bar.  What I want is for my bar to hug the left side of the screen, but for some reason it's being auto centered.   The code for my bar is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="icon-bar six-up left">
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/home.png">
                <label>Home</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/shipping.png">
                <label>Shipping</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/database.png">
                <label>Search</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/invoice.png">
                <label>Invoices</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/settings.png">
                <label>Settings</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/featured.png">
                <label>Bug Tracker</label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This sound in theory cause the bar to get left aligned to the edge of the screen.  I've also tried using CSS and using left: 0, position: absolute and those didn't work.  Using the developer tools window in Chrome I can see the extra area in which my bar should be able to fit, it just won't utilize it.  Does anyone know why this happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must be having other CSS afecting it i pasted your html into a codepen: 
http://codepen.io/pituki/pen/dcbpB

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="icon-bar six-up left">
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/home.png">
                <label>Home</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/shipping.png">
                <label>Shipping</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/database.png">
                <label>Search</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/invoice.png">
                <label>Invoices</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/settings.png">
                <label>Settings</label>
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <img class="small" src="images/32x32/featured.png">
                <label>Bug Tracker</label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use firebug if you are using firefox or chrome developer tools to inspect the element and see if there is another css rule afecting your centering.